# Customization for Visual Studio 2008 that opens MSDN Help in a browser when hitting F1

Tags: visual-studio, msdn

The MSDN help isn't very helpful in that its startup time is long and that it quite often doesn't get you to the correct help file. I always end up opening MSDN in a browser instead. Is there some customization for Visual Studio 2008 that opens MSDN Help in a browser when hitting F1?

Comment: Newer duplicate question (customize which browser the F1 help shortcut opens): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828388/how-to-change-visual-studio-help-f1-to-open-in-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

**1:** Remove the default key-binding for F1, via Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard > Help.F1Help

Then write a little macro (different ways to do this of course), to start your browser with a default URL e.g.

```
Sub OpenChromeWithURL()
Dim url As String = "http://msdn.microsoft.com"

'launch browser
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", url)
End Sub
```

To this macro you can now assign a keyboard shortcut as described before. Go to Tools > Options > Evnironment >Keyboard. Look for Macro.OpenChromeWithURL and assign a shortcut key to your Macro. An explanation on how to assign a shortcut key you can find here: [How to map a Visual Studio macro to a keyboard shortcut?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/05/02/how-to-map-a-visual-studio-macro-to-a-keyboard-shortcut.aspx)

---

**2:** Download the [MSDN Library for Visual Studio 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7bbe5eda-5062-4ebb-83c7-d3c5ff92a373&DisplayLang=en)