# How to change Visual Studio help (F1) to open in Chrome?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I press F1 in Visual Studio, it opens the MSDN website in Internet Explorer. I would like it to open in Google Chrome (as links do from other apps). How can I achieve that?

Google Chrome is my default browser in Windows.

Comment: Duplicate of an older question: [Customization for Visual Studio 2008 that opens MSDN Help in a browser when hitting F1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930962/customization-for-visual-studio-2008-that-opens-msdn-help-in-a-browser-when-hitt)

Answer (score 7):

- Open Visual Studio
- Click ‘Tools’ >> ‘Options…’
- In Options window, please select ‘Environment’ >> ‘Web Browser’ >> Click ‘Internet Explorer Options…’
- In Internet Properties window, please select Programs Tab.
- In Programs Tab, click ‘Set programs’ >> ‘Set your default programs’
- In this window, you could set your default for all file types and protocols it can open.

This is take from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/30afe492-7173-4c03-a671-02484e3fc560/cannot-open-visual-studio-2010-help-files-in-another-browsers

Comment: This was slightly different for me. 'Set your default programs' was 'Set Associations', which redirected me via pop-up dialog to Settings > System > Default Apps.

Internet Explorer is the last item on the list, and a final "are you sure you want to switch" pop-up appears. Pretty hidden, if you ask me.

Comment: Sadly, this option doesn't appear to be present in the 2022 edition.

Answer (score 1):

Make Google Chrome as your default browser then press F1 in visual studio, It will open the Msdn website in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It seems neither Windows nor Visual Studio currently provides any facility to change what browser Visual Studio will open with for the F1 documentation feature.

The best solution I've found so far is by using the [open source](https://github.com/aloneguid/bt) [Browser Tamer](https://www.aloneguid.uk/projects/bt/) tool.

After it detects your system's browser, you can create a rule for whichever browser you prefer, targetting the `devenv.exe` Process.

Answer (score -1):

Try the script below for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.onkeydown = function () {
        if (event.keyCode == 112) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }

    $(function () {
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode);
            switch (key) {
                case 112:
                    navigateUrl($('a[id$=lnk1]'));
                    break;
                default: ;
            }
        });
        function navigateUrl(jObj) {
            window.location.href = $(jObj).attr("href");
        }
    });       
</script>
```

and then make the hyperlink button

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="lnk1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="../Home.aspx" style="display:none;">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

so that it can call hyperlink on click of F1

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is asking about opening documentation in Visual Studio using F1, and this answer is about making a webapp that has an F1 option.